# Aperiodic SFT equal to a substitution subshift

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, tiling, symbolic-dynamics, aperiodic-tiling

I was wondering whether there are primitive symbolic substitutions over $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ whose associated subshift is equal to an aperiodic SFT. *By SFT here I mean a subshift of finite type, as in [this link](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symbolic_dynamics#Shifts_of_finite_type_and_sofic_shifts) or [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412560/minimality-of-aperiodic-sfts-for-mathbbz2).*

This might be a simple and trivial answer to this, but I was hoping some knowledgeable person will be able to clarify some of my confusion.

My understanding is that in one dimension, this is impossible since we can find a periodic sequence in the substitution subshift. One can see this by finding a cycle in a De-Brujin graph associated to the substitution subshift. I believe that in fact any minimal subshift in one dimension should contain some periodic sequence.

It is my understanding that in $2$ dimensions, the situation is different. I know that there are minimal SFTs which are aperiodic, since we can translate Wang tiles to SFTs in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$. I was wondering whether there is a constant 'length' substitution, given by $S:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{A}^{Q}$ for $Q=\prod_{j=1}^d\{ 0,1,...,m_{j}-1 \}$, such that its susbtitution subshift is an aperiodic SFT? I know of a paper by Sébastien Labbé that gives Wang tiles generated from a substitution, but I am unsure whether the Wang shift is a factor of the substitution subshift. It also does not seem clear to me, whether one can translate this result to a constant length subshift.

I've confused myself over this for some weeks now, and was wondering whether perhaps some knowledgeable source could help clarify this. I would appreciate any clarification on this subject and any new information on this topic.

Comment: can you expand the SFT acronym?

Comment: @kodlu I've added two links in an edit to hopefully clarify what I mean.

Comment: https://www.lacl.fr/pvanier/rech/cirm.pdf I think you are looking for intrinsically substitutive tile sets

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Goodman-Strauss Annals paper proves that any block substitution is MLD to an SFT?

Comment: @DanRust I think Thue-Morse times one-point subshift is not MLD to SFT, the vertical direction will stay periodic so you find doubly periodic points.

Comment: It's of course known that all substitutive subshifts are _sofic_, i.e. factors of SFT, with small extension (= kernel pair close to diagonal). The question is whether the extension can be injective, and the answer is yes, for a very specific substitution.

Comment: I couldn't find an MLD result even for aperiodic substitutive subshifts. GS doesn't seem to say anything about the extension.

Comment: @VilleSalo Thank you (again) for your answer. I think I saw this before, but have not been able to understand it. I still do not understand the substitution in figure 16.  Are the alphabet of the substitution essentially a triple corresponding to each layer?

Comment: "Are the alphabet of the substitution essentially a triple corresponding to each layer?" that is my understanding. I haven't read this in detail. It's not the only known construction anyway.